# MySQL Workbench doesn't refresh, this leads to many problems which can't exist

Tags: mysql, model, workbench

When I try to change my model in the mySQL Workbench and I want to synchronize it with my database by clicking:

Database -> Forward Engineer
there comes no problem.

I already just deleted all the associations and still it has problems with foreign keys when I try to do:

Database -> Synchronize Model

And now it has this problem:

Executing SQL script in server:

> ERROR: Error 1829: Cannot drop column 'idCase': needed in a foreign key constraint 'prodevcbr/fk_solution_case1' of table '"prodevcbr"."solution"'
>   SQL Code:

```
    ALTER TABLE `prodevcbr`.`Thecase` 
    DROP COLUMN `user_iduser`,
    DROP COLUMN `kindOfDamage_idkindOfDamage`,
    DROP COLUMN `pumpModel_idpumpModel`,
    DROP COLUMN `pumpElement_idpumpElement`,
    DROP COLUMN `createTime`,
    DROP COLUMN `idCase`,
    CHANGE COLUMN `figureOfMerit` `figureofmerit` DOUBLE NULL DEFAULT NULL AFTER `problemText`,
    ADD COLUMN `idThecase` INT(11) NOT NULL FIRST,
    ADD COLUMN `createTimeThecase` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL AFTER `idThecase`,
    DROP PRIMARY KEY,
    ADD PRIMARY KEY (`idThecase`),
    DROP INDEX `fk_thecase_user1_idx` ,
    DROP INDEX `fk_thecase_kindOfDamage1_idx` ,
    DROP INDEX `fk_thecase_pumpModel1_idx` ,
    DROP INDEX `fk_thecase_pumpElement1_idx`
```

SQL script execution finished: statements: 3 succeeded, 1 failed
Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch**

I don't understand the problem the mySQL Workbench has. Sometimes I just restart pc and the problem is solved. How can this be? It's already driving me nuts sitting here and searching for problems which do actually not make sense.

My model looks like this right now (without any associations):

http://www1.xup.to/exec/ximg.php?fid=13733054

Comment: "*Cannot drop column 'idCase': needed in a foreign key constraint*" seems pretty clear to me.

Comment: How can errors like this appear if there is no constraint between two classes? :D 

http://www1.xup.to/exec/ximg.php?fid=20821011